# Matrix in Matrix

Tags: custom-fields, ee1, matrix

Has anyone ever tried to create a matrix field in a matrix field? (nested matrix)

I have a workshop schedule I'm building and thought this would be the "best" way to create it for multiple days, (initial matrix), and events throughout the day, (nested matrix). I know there isn't a default option for this as far as fieldtypes in a matrix field, but I was curious as to whether or not the universe would implode if attempted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to give [Nolan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan) a try - it sounds like exactly what you're after.

> Nolan enables a very simple matrix style field within a Pixel & Tonic Matrix field

[image: Nolan screenshot]

Comment: I was just going to suggest Nolan.

Comment: Dom - That is exactly what I'm after. Unfortunately, I have to do this in EE1.

Comment: I ended up not being able to use Nolan due to version conflicts. Nolan would have done what I needed though so I awarded the answer here. See below for what I ended up doing for this instance.

Comment: By all means accept your own answer if that's the approach you've opted for. For future reference it's worth flagging any questions that are specific to EE1, as people are likely to assume you're referring to EE2 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Dom... I seem to inherit a lot of legacy sites. I wish I could update them all... I guess it's always a WIP.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Haven't attempted this, what I have done though is make a Channel for the "events", and then a multi-select Playa-field in the days-Matrix. It's not ideal, I understand, but maybe this would work for you?

Comment: Yeah. This is what I do on events now. This customer wanted a way to maintain each workshop independently on a per entry basis. I had started this with categories, and multi-weblog entries. I may be stuck with that unless I decide to write a custom plug-in which I don't think I have time for.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

If this were in EE2, Dom's usage of [Nolan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan) would be ideal for what I have. If anyone else runs into an older legacy site that needs the same, here is what I ended up with.

I built a matrix fieldtype with the sub-fields needed for the workshops. I installed [SC Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sc-category-select) and created a category group called workshop days which held nothing more than  'Day 1', 'Day 2', etc.

One of the fields in the matrix field is a [SC Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sc-category-select) field which allows them to select which day the information goes with.

Again, this may not be ideal, but it meets the clients needs of maintaining the workshops on a per entry basis.